# Android phone does not produce sound using cordova phone plugin & does not give error message

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am using the ionic framework to create an app. I would like to play a sound so I used https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media/
.
This is my piece of code used to play the sound:

```
var my_media = new Media('/android/assets/www/audio/National Anthem.mp3',
        // success callback
        function () { console.log("playAudio():Audio Success"); },
        // error callback
        function (err) {console.dir("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err); }
    );
     my_media.play();
```

Unfortunately its not playing and the error message given is:

```
playAudio():Audio Error: [object Object]
```

In which I cannot view the object on the chrome console!

If I replace `var my_media = new Media(..` with `var my_media =$cordovaMedia.newMedia(...` I dont get any message at all on the console. My code is placed in `$ionicPlatform.ready(function()..` so I know for sure that the plugin is ready before using it. Any sugesstions?

Comment: could you try out this sample working app in the following link which is non ionic based - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_Media

Comment: I'm looking for a direct solution rather than creating new things, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So my solution for media player is below:

First, create a service:

```
.factory('MediaSrv', function($q, $ionicPlatform, $window){
  var service = {
    loadMedia: loadMedia,
    getStatusMessage: getStatusMessage,
    getErrorMessage: getErrorMessage
  };

  function loadMedia(src, onError, onStatus, onStop){
    var defer = $q.defer();
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
      var mediaSuccess = function(){
        if(onStop){onStop();}
      };
      var mediaError = function(err){
        _logError(src, err);
        if(onError){onError(err);}
      };
      var mediaStatus = function(status){
        if(onStatus){onStatus(status);}
      };

      if($ionicPlatform.is('android')){src = '/android_asset/www/' + src;}
      defer.resolve(new $window.Media(src, mediaSuccess, mediaError,    mediaStatus));
    });
    return defer.promise;
  }

  function _logError(src, err){
    console.error('media error', {
      code: err.code,
      message: getErrorMessage(err.code)
    });
  }

  function getStatusMessage(status){
    if(status === 0){return 'Media.MEDIA_NONE';}
    else if(status === 1){return 'Media.MEDIA_STARTING';}
    else if(status === 2){return 'Media.MEDIA_RUNNING';}
    else if(status === 3){return 'Media.MEDIA_PAUSED';}
    else if(status === 4){return 'Media.MEDIA_STOPPED';}
    else {return 'Unknown status <'+status+'>';}
  }

  function getErrorMessage(code){
    if(code === 1){return 'MediaError.MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED';}
    else if(code === 2){return 'MediaError.MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK';}
    else if(code === 3){return 'MediaError.MEDIA_ERR_DECODE';}
    else if(code === 4){return 'MediaError.MEDIA_ERR_NONE_SUPPORTED';}
    else {return 'Unknown code <'+code+'>';}
 }

  return service;
})
```

Then, in controller:

```
.controller('phrasebookCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicPlatform, $timeout,    $cordovaMedia,MediaSrv) { 

    $scope.play = function(src){
    MediaSrv.loadMedia(src).then(function(media){
    media.play();
});
```

And in your view (on click Test me):

```
 <p>Welcome: <a  ng-click="play('audio/welcome1_el.mp3')">Test me</a></p>
```

Note: This solution works fine for Android and iOS platforms. Also you must create a folder with the name *audio* in www folder in your project, with the .mp3 files.

Please let me know if this solved your problem.

Comment: You're a genius :)

Comment: Glad to know that this solution helped you! :) :)

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: **cdvfile** path is supported as **src** parameter:

```
var my_media = new Media('cdvfile://localhost/temporary/recording.mp3', ...);
```

Please set your path according to that.

Comment: Can you please explain to me what a cdvfile path means and how my path will look like if I need to use it?